# Moving backed up Wordpress from subdirectory to root

Tags: wordpress

I have a question regarding moving a backup from http://websitename/subdirectory.com to http://websitename.com.

What is the best approach to do this?

I have the backup from the subdirectory on my pc and currently on the website root there is a clean Wordpress installation.

There are alot of pictures, the Avada theme there and other media files.
If I just copy the files via FTP will it crash or will the URLs be broken afterwards?

Comment: There are a lot of guides on the Internet about moving a WordPress site from a subdirectory to the main domain. Have you tried any of them yet?

Comment: For example: https://www.hostpapa.com/knowledgebase/move-wordpress-subdomain-root-domain/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take a couple of steps to but here is the basic steps required.

1. Download the database from phpmyadmin (or however you access your sites database).
2. You should have a .sql file now.
3. You need to do a search and replace action on the full url for the site in the subfolder to the new location where it will live at the root.  Your goal here is to get the subfolder out of every url on your site.  Example, your current url is this: https://example.com/subfolder/ - you will need it to be https://example.com/
4. Save that version of your database as a new file called import.sql.
5. To be safe, I would create a new database, database user, and database password and import this new version into it.  Store these values database name, database user, database password and database hostname. You will need them later.

**Plugins**
Download all of the plugins from /subfolder/wp-content/plugins/ folder and upload those to the /wp-content/plugins/ folder in your root level fresh install of wordpress.

**Themes**
Upload your theme to the /wp-content/themes/ folder from your /subfolder/wp-content/themes/ folder.

**Uploads**
Download everything in the /subfolder/wp-content/uploads/ folder and upload to the /wp-content/uploads/ folder.

**Update your wp-config.php**
That database that you created and imported your database in Step 1 here, you'll need to update your wp-config.php with the new database name, database user, database password and database host.

The last step here is to upload the wp-config.php to the root file and this will point the site to the new database.

**Login to wp-admin**
Login to wordpress at the root example.com/wp-admin/. Go to Permalinks settings and save them.  Sometimes you have to do that to flush the permalinks and make subpages work.

**Test your site**
Go the frontend of your site and test everything to make sure that everything is in working order.

Comment: I have a question, I did as you said, but it appears that the pages and media files are missing. Why could this be?

Comment: Is it possible that the database URL change is bad? (step 3). Before it was http://example/subfolder.com and now it's https://example.com (http before, now https).

Comment: Did you for sure upload all of your media to the root /wp-content/uploads/ folder?  I've moved a many wordpress sites, it is ok to change the url in the database, but you might want to make sure that you changed every instance of it.  I'd pull the database back down again and do some different searches to see if you still see the old urls in there.  First try /subfolder as a term to search for in your database.  Also, go to settings->general tab and make sure those urls are set correctly.

Comment: Also double check that when you did the search & replace, you didn't create any broken urls.